# awk command stops the command from completing and returning exit code

Tags: awk, solaris, posix, exit-status, hang

I'm on `SunOS 5.11 11.1 sun4v sparc sun4v`

I wish to grab capture the result (success or failed) `$?` of a command.

The below works fine.

```
ps auxww | grep httpd;
echo $?
```

Output:

```
1
```

But when i add the `awk` to capture the return code `1` it hangs and never returns as shown below.

```
ps auxww | grep httpd; awk -vrc=$? 'BEGIN{print "rc="rc)'
```

No output and does not even return ... simply hangs!!

I want the command to work on all OS types like Linux, AiX and Solaris.

Can you please suggest ho can i get the command to return `rc=$?` in the standard out ?

Comment: 1. Please copy-paste the **exact** command you're using, your awk will fail because of a syntax error. 2. your system has an old-style awk installed as `/bin/awk` or `/usr/bin/awk`, make sure you're using a "new awk" -- **try replacing the `awk` with `nawk`.** 3. why not just `echo "rc=$?" ;-)

Comment: With `echo` the issue is resolved @user414777